# boto3 SQS message_id vs MessageId

Tags: boto3

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/997

I see that `message.message_id` is different from `body['MessageId']`? What is the difference between the two?

```
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
queue_obj = sqs.Queue(queue_url)
messages = queue_obj.receive_messages(
            AttributeNames=['All'],
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            VisibilityTimeout=15,
            WaitTimeSeconds=20,
            MaxNumberOfMessages=5
)
for message in messages:
    body = json.loads(message.body)
    print(str(message.message_id) == str(body['MessageId'])) # This prints False all the time
```

Answer (score 0):

The `message.message_id` corresponds to the ID that SQS assigns to the message as shown in the boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Message.message_id).

As to the `message.body`, the value is whatever the sender of the message set its body to. So the existence and value of `MessageId` in the `body` was because of the message's sender as well.

Comment: Thanks. I would like know which Id is going to be unique in a queue? I would like to store messages by id as key